# Windows System Notification Event Service & Custom Events

Tags: c#, windows, events, publish

I know with the Windows System Notification Event Service (SNES) I can subscribe to many different system events.

Is it possible to create my own type of System Event and publish events to the System Notification Event Service?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried developing your own COM object and seeing if these events are captured by the SENS service?  If so, you should be able to create a listener based on the CLSID.